# How do I insert a line after a paragraph in Word?

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop, shapes

I want to add a paragraph and then draw a line shape under it. I know how to add the line, I just can't figure out how to get the position under the paragraph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for? http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.inlineshape%28v=office.11%29.aspx

Comment: Not exactly, but this accomplishes the same thing, so points to you, liquid!